# Prevent xargs from appending a dot at the end of the term

Tags: xargs, cut

I am trying to use the gdrive command line app via a script. The output of `gdrive` is whitespace delimited, and I need to process further the first term (which is a filename) of the output with a `command2` (e.g. download/delete/etc.)

The output of `gdrive list --many options` looks like this

```
1zioW5nrKdWPz-UiaGla1KJkcMf-OUGfR   test.sh   bin   396.0 B   2019-07-24 03:28:26
```

So I do

```
gdrive list --many options | cut -w -f1 | xargs -I {} gdrive delete {}
```

But this gives an error

```
Failed to get file: googleapi: Error 404: File not found: 1zioW5nrKdWPz-UiaGla1KJkcMf-OUGfR., notFound
```

Why is xargs appending the dot at the end and how can I stop it?

As an alternative, I also tried piping out to `(read A; gdrive delete $A)` instead of via `xargs`, but the output is the same.

To diagnose the issue (on the suggestion of @michael-homer) -  On piping out to `hexdump` instead of `gdrive delete` (by appending at the end `xargs -I {} printf '<<%s>>\n' {} | hexdump -C`), the output looks like

```
00000000  3c 3c 31 7a 69 6f 57 35  6e 72 4b 64 57 50 7a 2d  |<<1zioW5nrKdWPz-|
00000010  55 69 61 47 6c 61 31 4b  4a 6b 63 4d 66 2d 4f 55  |UiaGla1KJkcMf-OU|
00000020  47 66 52 3e 3e 0a                                 |GfR>>.|
00000026
```

Comment: Need a realistic output sample to understand the problem. What you have doesn't help

Comment: done. updated q with more detail.

Comment: If it is tab whitespace delimited output you should use `awk '{print $1}'` instead of `cut -w -f1`  , since `-w` is not supported universally

Comment: Yeah, I had/have that (awk instead of cut) already...makes no difference...

Comment: Can you add an `echo` before `gdrive delete` and see what comes out? There should not be a dot there. If there is, we have follow-up diagnostics to try, but otherwise it's likely a different problem.

Comment: @MichaelHomer You are a wise man. I was just doing that. On checking the previous output with an `echo` in the `xargs` instead of `gdrive delete` there is indeed no dot at the end.

Comment: Ok, try `| xargs -I {} printf '<<%s>>\n' {} | hexdump -C` and check that it looks like the right sort of text - one possibility is some non-printing character that gets turned into a dot in the output. Otherwise, it's something inside the gdrive command and I have no idea what that'd be.

Comment: I think the hexdump output looks okay. Just updated the question with it.

Comment: What happens if you just run `gdrive delete 1zioW5nrKdWPz-UiaGla1KJkcMf-OUGfR`?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Oh, that works very nicely. The file gets deleted.

Comment: @MichaelHomer As an alternative, I also tried piping out to `(read A; gdrive delete $A)` instead of via `xargs`, but the output is the same.

Comment: Yeah, that looks normal. No clue at all what's going on then, but it's not coming from xargs.

Comment: Yeah... seems like that... problem seems to be with `gdrive delete` probably... guess I need to make an issue on github..

Comment: How do you know it's not just `gdrive` adding the dot in its formatting of the error message. Are you using the `gdrive -delete` command correctly (I've never used it)?

Comment: Yes sir, I am using `gdrive delete` correctly. If you look about 6 comments up, you will see someone asked what happens if I do `gdrive delete filenamexxx` and indeed it works fine. It is just the piping through that somehow adds a dot at the end.